# xsd xs:unique failed to detect duplicates

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, unique, xml-namespaces

I have a XSD file:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="library"
           xmlns="library"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="library">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="book" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:unique name="book-name">
            <xs:selector xpath="book"/>
            <xs:field xpath="name"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="book">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

And a xml-instance:

```
<library xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="library uniqueness.xsd"
         xmlns="library">
    <book>
        <name>Hihi</name>
    </book>
    <book>
        <name>Hihi</name>
    </book>
</library>
```

I use [this](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html) validator to test my documents.

What I supposed is, the XML instance should be invalid as both book names in a library is `Hihi`, which means each book name is not unique at all.

I have tried adding namespace prefix to everything, moving the `xs:unique` elements to element `book`, but all those does not work and the XML validators says the document is valid.

What have I done wrong? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "I have tried adding namespace prefix to everything",
but seemingly you made a mistake there, because that's the issue of your schema.

Regular namespace declarations do not apply to XPath expressions.

In XML Schema 1.1, you could simply add `xpathDefaultNamespace="##defaultNamespace"` to the `xs:schema` element.

In XML Schema 1.0, it is necessary to add an explicit prefix for the default namespace and use that prefix in constraints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="library"
           xmlns="library"
           xmlns:lib="library"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="library">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="book" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:unique name="book-name">
            <xs:selector xpath="lib:book"/> <!-- Prefixed -->
            <xs:field xpath="lib:name"/>    <!-- Prefixed -->
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="book">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Note that `library` is not a good namespace name. It should be a proper URI, for example `http://example.com/library`, but of course for your own domain. The URI does not need to be dereferenceable, but it should be unique in order to abvoid name conflicts.

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow-up question though. Why is namespace prefix compulsory when specifying XPath? What is the intention behind the standard?

Comment: I do not know the reasoning for that decision. However, it simply seems like an omission, because it was "corrected" in XSD 1.1 with the `xpathDefaultNamespace` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

as the answer before was right, you can also modify your xsd to :

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

and in your XML :

```
 <library xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```